# What is the correct ConnectionString to pass SQLConnect?

Tags: c, windows

I've found a good example on the MSDN site. [SQLConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714163%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I want to connect to an SQL server, to my database, but unfortunately, SQLConnect always returns -1, and the application freezes.

I have edited the code above:

```
direxec::direxec() 
{
_mbscpy_s( chr_ds_name, MAX_DATA, ( const unsigned char * )"Server=mySQLServer;Database=myDatabaseName;" );
_mbscpy_s( uid, MAX_DATA, ( const unsigned char * )"testuser" );
_mbscpy_s( pwd, MAX_DATA, ( const unsigned char * )"testpassword" );
printf("\n%s",chr_ds_name);
}

void direxec::sqlconn() 
{    
SQLAllocEnv( &henv );
SQLAllocConnect( henv, &hdbc );

 rc = SQLConnect( hdbc, chr_ds_name, SQL_NTS, uid, SQL_NTS, pwd, SQL_NTS );

// Deallocate handles, display error message, and exit.
if ( !MYSQLSUCCESS( rc ) ) 
{
    printf( "\nFailed %d",rc );
    SQLFreeConnect( henv );
    SQLFreeEnv( henv );
    SQLFreeConnect( hdbc );
    if ( hstmt ) error_out();
    exit( -1 );
}
printf("\nConnected");
rc = SQLAllocStmt( hdbc, &hstmt );
}
```

Using SQLDriverConnect i can connect to my database, but i want to use SQLConnect if it is possible.
Does anyone have any idea what am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlConnect` doesn't accept a connection string, it only accepts a Data Source Name (DSN).  DSN's are configured in the ODBC Administration Tool in Administrative Tools.  If you want to use a connection string then you need to use `SqlDriverConnect`